# Multiple Filters in Material Component DataTable in Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, angular-material2

> I need help regarding multi filters. I used material datatable filters
>   but it filtered whole grid but i need to customized filters. In single
>   grid i need a filter which will search via different columns.

Below is my code of .ts file which work properly as filtered the whole grid.

```
 import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

    import { MatTableDataSource, MatSort, MatPaginator } from '@angular/material'
    import { importType } from '@angular/compiler/src/output/output_ast';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-grid',
      templateUrl: './grid.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./grid.component.scss']
    })
    export class GridComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

      grantsearch = [];

      @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
      @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;

      dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(ELEMENT_DATA);
      displayedColumns = ['number', 'title', 'agency', 'status', 'posted', 'closed'];

      constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
  }

  applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    filterValue = filterValue.trim(); // Remove whitespace
    filterValue = filterValue.toLowerCase(); // MatTableDataSource defaults to lowercase matches
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue;
  }
```

.html file for

```
 <div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">
        <div class="example-header">
            <mat-form-field>
                <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Filter">
            </mat-form-field>
        </div>

           </div>
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. What exactly is your problem? What's the current and the desired behaviour?

Comment: @bugs i am consuming a wordpress api in angular 5 just to show data in grid and i grid i used filter(search), the grid table and filter which i used is material component.
When is use filter for search its searched in whole grid but i want to specify filter in specific column and want to use different material filter in single grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the default behaviour of the filter by specifying your own `filterPredicate`. I.e., to filter only on the `name` column:

```
this.dataSource.filterPredicate = function(data, filter: string): boolean {
    return data.name.toLowerCase().includes(filter);
}
```

[Working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-811zan)